# Are there any special considerations when cutting powder-coated metal?

Tags: metal, metal-cutting, sheet-metal

I have a thin powder-coated steel sheet which I'd like to cut into panels.

I've never cut powder-coated metal before.

Are there any considerations I need to make when doing so?

Comment: I have never paid much attention to the paint or power powder coat but usually do wear a dust mask when using an abrasive cutoff disk. When I use the metal skill saw or band saw I don’t wear a mask. The big difference is afterwards the powder coating is not burnt like paint will be unless I use a torch.

Comment: Don't get it wet, don't put it in bright light, and never, never cut it after midnight!